# How does cardinality affect the dimension of an extension field?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

As an example:

Let p be an odd prime.  When α, β ∈ $\mathbb{Z}$<sub>p</sub> are not squares, then α / β is a square.  Let L, K both be fields of size p<sup>2</sup>.

The rest of the exercise is irrelevant to what I am trying to learn here.  I am reading the solution to the exercise and it says that:

[L : $\mathbb{Z}$<sub>p</sub>] = 2

Why is this exactly?  I am not sure if I am missing something obvious, or if there was some detail that I missed in class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any field extension $F\subseteq F^\prime$ the degree $[F^\prime:F]$ is defined to be the dimension of $F^\prime$ as vector space over $F$, i.e.
$$
[F^\prime:F]=\dim_F(F^\prime).
$$
Thus, in the case of finite fields where, say, $F=\Bbb F_p$ (the field with $p$ elements) there is an equality
$$
|L|=p^{\dim_{\Bbb F_p}(L)}=p^{[F^\prime:F]}
$$
because it is true for every vector field $V$ that the choice of a basis ${e_1,...,e_d}$ defines an identification $V\simeq\Bbb F_p^d$ and thus $|V|=p^d$.

Comment: Just need to clarify one point: L is the field that I posed in the question of size $p^2$, correct?

Comment: @JamesNorton: what I wrote holds for *every* field $L$. Thus, $L$ is a quadratic extension of $\Bbb F_p$ if and only if $|L|=p^2$.